# Java GUI Fullscreen for Multiple Screens

Tags: java, user-interface, awt, fullscreen, monitors

I hope I'm not posting a duplicate question, but I wasn't able to find a question like this so maybe I'm safe? Anyway...

For the applications that I'm making, I'm going to have two applications (two separate processes and windows) open at the same time. The computer on which these applications will be running on will have multiple monitors. I want the first application/ window to fullscreen and occupy one of my monitors (easy part), and the other one to be fullscreen on the second monitor. If possible, I would like for them to initialize this way.

At the moment, I am making my windows fullscreen by using this code:

```
this.setVisible(false);
this.setUndecorated(true);
this.setResizable(false);
myDevice = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(this);
```

The class that this is in is an extension of the JFrame class and myDevice is of the type "GraphicsDevice". It's certainly possible that there's a better way to make my window fullscreen so that I can have two different applications fullscreen over two different monitors.

If I was unclear in any way, please say and I'll try to edit in clarifications!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to position your frames on each screen devices.

```
frame1.setLocation(pointOnFirstScreen);
frame2.setLocation(pointOnSecondScreen);
```

Then to maximize a frame, simply call this on your JFrame:

```
frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Here is a working example illustrating that:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {
    protected void initUI() {
        Point p1 = null;
        Point p2 = null;
        for (GraphicsDevice gd : GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()) {
            if (p1 == null) {
                p1 = gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().getLocation();
            } else if (p2 == null) {
                p2 = gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().getLocation();
            }
        }
        if (p2 == null) {
            p2 = p1;
        }
        createFrameAtLocation(p1);
        createFrameAtLocation(p2);
    }

    private void createFrameAtLocation(Point p) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Test frame on two screens");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JTextArea textareaA = new JTextArea(24, 80);
        textareaA.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));
        panel.add(textareaA, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setLocation(p);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello,

 Thanks for the prompt reply! However, that didn't seem to do anything. I commented what I had used before to set my frame to full-screen and added that, and yes, both of the applications went full screen, but they were both still on the same monitor.

 What I needed was to make two applications full screen but on separate monitors. (Upon initialization as well, if possible)

Comment: @Sephallia I update my post with a fully-working example that dispatches two frames on two screens (if you have 2 screens of course). The trick is to position the frame on two separate screen and then maximize them.

Comment: Hey, I didn't really need full working examples. The part you were missing before was the setLocation. I thought I might need to involve that, but I really didn't know what I might need to use for a "point". Thank you very much! I'd upvote your post, but I still don't have 15 reputation x:. Sorry!

Comment: Oh okay, thank you! I also just got another 5 reputation, so I went ahead and upvoted it. Thanks again!